# ¿Por qué no me sale redondeado el resultado?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo dos variables en *NodeJS* con estos valores:

```js
valor1 = 3.06;
valor2 = 2.20;

console.log("Resultado de la resta 3.06 - 2.20", valor1 - valor2);
```

El resultado que me esta dando es *0.8599999999* en vez de darme *0.86* dado a que solo tienen dos decimales después de la coma.

¿Por qué ocurre esto?

Comment: Debes redondear el resultado. Te dejo este link con la librería https://www.npmjs.com/package/round-to

Comment: No debes usar una libreria, puedes indicar cuantos decimales quieres que te salgan con la funcion .toFixed(decimal). Ejemplo: const valor3 = valor1- valor2; console.log(valor3.toFixed(2));

Comment: Si, pero mi pregunta es porque he de redondearlo si al final los dos números que estoy usando son de dos decimales solamente después de la coma, es de suponer que el resultado tiene que dar igual, solo dos decimales, estoy restando o sumando, no multiplicando ni dividiendo que hay si me va a dar mas de dos decimales posiblemente, lo que no entiendo es porque en una operación tan sencilla me saca tantos decimales

Comment: Si lees un poco la respuesta que te dio ArtEze encontrarás que es algo raro por la especificaciones de la iEEE754 el coma flotante

Comment: Ahhh, disculpa, cuando respondí no me había salido ese comentario, gracias